# httpPost request formation for java ! using data provided by fiddler o/p

Tags: android, post, http-headers, http-post

This is my fiddler report of a post request from my browser ! I can see the post data ! The question is how to add this data if i make the post request from java e.g say using httpPost method. My question is what to write at httpPost.addheader("","");

```
    POST    http://reactomews.oicr.on.ca:8080/ReactomeRESTfulAPI/RESTfulWS/queryHitPathways HTTP/1.1
    Host: reactomews.oicr.on.ca:8080
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 41
    Accept: application/json
    Origin: http://reactomews.oicr.on.ca:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like        Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
    Content-type: text/plain
    Referer:http://reactomews.oicr.on.ca:8080/ReactomeRESTfulAPI/ReactomeRESTFulAPI.html
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

    PPP2R1A,CEP192,AKAP9,CENPJ,CEP290,DYNC1H1 // this sequence of data I have to add in my post request from java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For android I use [Loopj - Android-asyc-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) for REST requests and it's POST is EXTREMELY easy to use! Give it a try and let me know if it worked for you! 
Hope it helped! :)